# PHP reorder array keys from certain key onward, looping back around

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have an array:

```
$array = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
```

Obviously they're indexed 0-6.

I want to feed in a specific key index, and then reorder the array, beginning with that key, then going through the rest in the same order, like so:

```
print_r(somefunction(3, $array));
```

which would print this:

```
array
(
    '0'=>'Wed',
    '1'=>'Thu',
    '2'=>'Fri',
    '3'=>'Sat',
    '4'=>'Sun',
    '5'=>'Mon',
    '6'=>'Tue'
)
```

Is there a core function that would do this, or does anyone have a quick solution?

**UPDATE**

Here's my final function, slightly bigger in scope than my question above, which utilizes AbraCadaver's answer:

```
public static function ordered_weekdays($format = 'abr')
{
    $array = $format == 'full' ? array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday') : array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
    return array_merge(array_splice($array, get_option('start_of_week'), count($array)-1), $array);
}
```

Because it's a nice one-liner, I didn't need to make it a separate function.

Comment: split array on index number then add first part to second

Comment: My question did not deserve a downvote, whoever did that. Thank, user1954544. That's an obvious solution that eluded me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before and thought it was simpler than this, but here is what my brain says at the moment:

```
$index = 3;
$array = array_merge(array_splice($array, $index, count($array)-1), $array);
```

Comment: Very nice one-liner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines...

```
function reorder($x,$y)
{
    $c = count($y);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        $newArray[$i] = $y[$x];
        $x++;
        if ($x > $c) $x = 0;
    }
    return($newArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function somefunction($n, array $a) {
    $x = array_slice($a, 0, $n);
    $y = array_slice($a, $n);
    return array_merge($y, $x);
}

// forget this: uneccessary looping...
function somefunction($n, array $a) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
                array_push($a, array_shift($a));
        }
        return $a;
}
```

Comment: Nice edit. I liked the original, but not looping is preferable. Trying the new one now.

Comment: I shortened yours a bit:
function somefunction($n, array $a) {
    return array_merge(array_slice($a, $n), array_slice($a, 0, $n));
}